# Where should a classic ASP redirect go?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Should  the code below go in the `<head>` ?
Or should there be nothing else in the page besides the code below?

```
<%
    Response.Redirect "http://www.sitename.com/?" & Request.QueryString
%>
```

Comment: Can we get a bit of clarity on the question? (as I don't see any 'code below').  Do you mean Response.Redirect? It can go anywhere, often used as part of an If This Then etc

Answer (score 3):

As long as you have [response buffering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526001(v=vs.90).aspx) enabled and you haven't called `Response.Flush`, you can perform a `Response.Redirect` anywhere in the page. Buffering causes all ASP code to be executed before any of the page is sent to the browser. Thus if you perform a redirect within the code after `<head>`, none of the HTML will be sent to the browser and thus the redirect header will be sent correctly.

Buffering is typically enabled by default in IIS these days. To be safe, you could include this line near the top of your ASP page:

```
Response.Buffer = True
```

Comment: And to keep things clean, don't forget to close any open database connections before any response.redirect

Answer (score 1):

Classic ASP is server side code, `<head>` along with all html is client side code.  If you have this line in a .asp page then there's no point in having anything else on the page as users will never get a chance to see it.

That line would make more sense if it was inside a conditional statement - eg

```
<%
    If Request.QueryString("id") <> "" then
    Response.Redirect "http://www.sitename.com/?" & Request.QueryString("id")
    End If
%>
```

Here the user would only be bounced to another page if a value for `id` was provided in the url, otherwise any client side code in the page would be sent to the browser